# How to start reading from x line in a text file with python

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, text-files

I am dealing with a large text file on my windows machine, and I want a script that can print out lines from said text fill starting with a given line index.

```
with open('big_file.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f[1000]:
        print line
```

Something like the above except that actually works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice):

```
import itertools

with open('big_file.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in itertools.islice(f, 1000, None):
        print line
```

Comment: Just be ware that this still reads the first 1000 lines.  It just does not print them.

Comment: @hpaulj, You're right. This just skips the first 1000 lines.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `next(f)` to skip one line and use it with `for` loop.

```
with open('big_file.txt', 'r') as f:

    for x in range(1000):
        next(f)

    for line in f:
        print line
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use `readlines` and then start iterating from the given index:

```
with open('big_file.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines()[1000:]:
        print line
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This should be avoided because this load all lines into a list.